# Setting an "unidentified" network as "Home" automatically

Tags: windows-7, networking, powershell, homegroup

I have a (wired) network consisting of two Windows 7 (x86) PCs, a HP network printer, and a gigabit network switch. There's no router or DCHP, so they all have fixed IPs in the 192.168.0.xxx region. There's very little chance of any other devices being added to this network and there will **never** be internet access.

One of the computers is frequently used to remote desktop in to the other. Files are transferred by a shared folder in both directions from both machines. Both machines belong to the same homegroup.

The problem is this: When either computer is rebooted, they do not recognise the network, and designate it as "public". They won't share folders or accept incoming remote desktop requests from this public network. Is there a way to either make all networks default to "Home", or a script (powershell/cmd both acceptable) run on startup/network connection to make the network tagged as home?

Answer (score 2):

As the network has no name nor gateway, Windows can't memorize it, I guess.
You may want to allow file sharing when being in a "public" network (if the computers can't access Internet that's not a problem).
Some documentation about it: http://www.howtogeek.com/school/windows-network-sharing/lesson3/all/

Comment: That sounds like a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to switch off 1 computer, 
than change settings in other they to become home network.
And after that devices should remember this combination.

Comment: They don't remember the network. Also at some points, all devices on the network will have to be powered down.

Comment: I would recommend then, to use router instead of switch, coz it can create network and other devices will join it.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).